# Avoid warning with PHP specific version code

Tags: php

An application that i develope run on different version of PHP.
There are some pieces of code that are PHP version dependent like this example:

```
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.0.0') >= 0) {
            $salt = random_bytes(22);
} else {
            //Use for php < 7
            $salt = mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
}
```

Any php code checker of any IDE give a warning on every deprecated functions.
How can I avoid that?

Does exist any PHPDoc annotation that i can use to exclude that warning ?

Comment: notwithstanding that you should heed warnings, you can use a phpdoc statement similar to : `/** @noinspection PhpDeprecationInspection */`  , works for me, but not very often in my code bases.  I usually follow with a `todo : fix this mess` so i can remember to fix this sore point.